# Simplifying function and finding domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $g(x)=x+5$ and $h(x)=4/x$. Find the domain of the following function then simplify the expression.

$(g/h)(x)$

I'm getting all mixed up because of the double fraction. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean the function $\dfrac {g(x)}{h(x)}$?

Comment: Either way, user, what value of $x$ will certainly cause trouble?

Comment: yes  g(x)/h(x) no x value is given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$ $$\dfrac {g(x)}{h(x)} = \dfrac{x+5}{\dfrac 4x} =  \dfrac{x+5}{\dfrac 4{\cancel{x}}}\times \frac{x}{\cancel{x}} =\dfrac{x(x+5)}{4},\quad x\neq 0$$

Can you see why the function is not defined for $x = 0$?

Certainly, $h(x) = \dfrac 4x$ is not defined at $x=0$, so $\dfrac {g(x)}{h(x)} $ is not defined at $x = 0$